# PHP variable does not parse correctly using accepted answers for passing into javascript

Tags: javascript, php

It would seem this is not a new question, but after reading all the answer I can find, I'm still stuck.

I have a bit of php into which a snippet of javascript has been inserted:

```
<?php
function post_iframe_message( $msg ) {
                ?>
                <script>
                window.onload = function msgchild() {
                        console.log("called msgchild");
//                      obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify("Hello from parent"));
                        var val = "<?php echo $msg ?>";
                        obj = JSON.parse(var);
                        var e = document.getElementById('iframepm');
console.log(e);
                        e.contentWindow.postMessage(obj,'*');
                }
                </script>
                <?php

                echo "<script>iframepm.contentWindow.postMessage($msg,'*');</script>";
        }

?>
```

I am calling this function with:

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user()
post_iframe_message(json_encode($current_user));
```

I don't think the Wordpress bit is relevant other than to provide context for the variable object $current_user.

When this loads, I receive an 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier' error in the DevTools (Chrome) console.

If I comment out the (attempted) parsing of the $msg object and simply pass the string literal "Hello from parent" everything works great i.e. postMessage succeeds without error.

This is so simple that it kills me to ask the question here, but at this point I'm just tucking my pride up in a little ball and putting it in the corner. What obvious bit am I missing?

My line in question is line 29 of my code. The syntax error is being reported on line 346 which hints at something really stupid like a missed quote. Again, swapping comments to:

```
                        obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify("Hello from parent"));
//                      var val = "<?php echo $msg ?>";
//                      obj = JSON.parse(var);
```

and everything works. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance and I hope this has provided you with a good newbie chuckle. :-)

Comment: `JSON.parse(var);` <-- should be `val`.

Comment: Or just wrap your `<?php echo $msg; ?>` in `JSON.parse()`

Comment: @vlaz - oops. Good catch. Did not change my issue, but it would have been a problem at some point. Thank you.

Comment: @Tim Lewis  Thanks as well. It cleaned up a line of code and changed the error message. It is now:  Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list.  The line referenced is 212 lines after my code which would seem to indicate a missed closing quote/bracket/something.

Comment: OK, I got it. There appears to be some funny business in the WP_User object that doesn't respond too well to a json_encode request. Pulling out individual fields, creating my own object, and then using JSON to prep the message to postMessage works fine.